# Change Boot Device Windows / Linux

Tags: linux, windows, boot

I have a notebook here (HP 350 G2) with a build in HDD device with installed Windows 8. I now bought a SSD to add it as additional (primary) device.

I remove the HDD completely and replaced it with the SSD. Then I installed Linux Mint on this device without any problems. Now I connect the old win8-hdd (via CD Rom Caddy) back the laptop.

The problem: with both connected storages the pc always boots from the windows HDD (if I disconnect the HDD the Linux boot works as expected). When i enter the boot options (esc on boot) i can manual select the ssd with linux to boot

I tried all BIOS options to change boot orders, but nothing worked. Can somebody explain to me what I have to do, to:

- boot Linux per default from the (now internal) SSD
- have the Windows HDD as second device (per CD caddy) for additional storage (i want to keep the Windows hdd in this runnable state if it is possible, if I need to boot Windows again for some reason)

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed it based on:

https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/EFI_Problembehebung/

i deactiveated the Windows-Boot Manager with the command

sudo efibootmgr -b XXXXX -A

Works as expected.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts
of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become
invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

There might be different methods. You might try to edit the entry manually in etc/grub.d or try this:

> Boot on Linux and mount the harddisk(partition) with Windows.
>
> Open the bash(command line) and type:
>
> sudo os-prober
>
> Check if your Windows OS was found, and type:
>
> sudo update-grub
>
> Note , you could directly run ,sudo update-grub, but ,sudo os-prober, is to be sure.